# Form Submit Button Never Submits Form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making a form using MVC 4:

**View:**

```
@model etc.Models.FormViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("NewForm", "Form", FormMethod.Post))
{
       // html helpers here ...

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5">
                <button type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewForm()
    {

        FormViewModel newForm = new FormViewModel(); //this will never get hit
        return View();
    }
```

Clicking submit doesn't do anything.  It just makes the page scroll up a little higher and focus on a particular input field.  When I populate that field, and other fields, and click submit again, NewForm() is never called, regardless of whether or not I include `[HttpPost]` at the top of the controller action.  How do I make it so that when you click the submit button, NewForm() is called?  How do I actually pass the form data to NewForm()?

Comment: Verify that you're making a POST request in your browser's debug network monitor or with a tool like Fiddler.

Comment: I tried this just now, but it's not firing off any POST requests.

Comment: Do you have any javascript intercepting submit requests? Try turning off any data validations if you are using any.

Comment: Does your model have any attributes that are not being met when submitting your form?  You may be getting client side validation errors.

Comment: @MikeV Adding `Html.ValidationSummary` to the bottom helped me fix the issue.  The form was being POSTed with validation errors that it wasn't displaying, related to a malformed `Html.DropdownListFor`. Thank you.

Comment: Cool beans!  Glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that form submission was being prevented due to MVC 4 <strike>server-side</strike> client-side validation errors.  Without using `@Html.ValidationSummary`, it was hard for me to see those errors at the time.

Comment: If the NewForm() controller method marked with the HttpPost attribute never fired then it was client side validation rules that were preventing the form from submitting, not server-side validation rules. Server side validation rules would have fired inside of the NewForm() method and could be checked using the ModelState. The validation summary displays client side validation errors when available and if you have server-side validation that occurs and add errors to the ModelState the validation summary will also display those. It's important to know the difference.